# Segmentation fault inside printf statement

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, printf

I get a Segmentation fault inside the insert function within the printf statment

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void Insert(char w[])
{
int j;
int n=5;
printf("word is %s AFTER\n", w);
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        FILE *fp;
        if (argc !=2)
                fp=fopen("words.txt", "r");
        else
                fp=fopen(argv[1], "r");
        char line[28];
        while(!feof(fp)){
                fgets(line, 256, fp);
                Insert(line);
        }
}
```

in word.txt its just a bunch of words on each line i.e.

```
apple
banana
...
zoo
```

(... just means a bunch of words in between)
it prints this:

```
word is apple
AFTER
word is banana
AFTER
...(a bunch more repetitions)                                    
word is cookie
Segmentation Fault(core dumped)
```

Why is there a segmentation fault? it printed the word perfectly. And it didn't print the `AFTER`

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think this is the error but why do you read up to 256 bytes into an array where you only have 28b? Change line[28] to line[256] and see if that helps.

Comment: `char line[28];` then `fgets(line, 256, fp);` seems nasty. You can have a [very nice solution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sizeof) for this.

Comment: `char line[28];` => `char line[256];`

Comment: That's what happens when you try to put 256 pounds of potatoes in a 28 pound bag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Allocated memory only 28 bytes where as trying to copy 256 byte.

```
char line[28]; <-- 28 bytes only allocated to line.
        while(!feof(fp)){
                fgets(line, 256, fp); <-- 256 bytes read into line.
```

Increase the memory for `line` to avoid this issue.

Comment: please don't use duplicate constant sizes! I'd suggest using `sizeof(line)` instead.

Comment: @H2CO3: Please, don't clutter the code with superfluous parentheses. `sizeof line` is sufficient.